# Spring Boot as a resource server (JWK validation) & Angular/Cordova as front end - OAuth2 for social Login (Facebook & Google) support

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, google-oauth, spring-oauth2, oauth2client

I am stuck with the implementation of spring boot as a resource server for multiple authorization servers for validating the access/id tokens provided by authorization servers (such as google, facebook via front end libraries). Here is the architecture I am looking for the below desired flow as a working model.

[Desired Architecture Image - Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ4r7.jpg)

**what I implemented so far**: I used a library angularx-social-login on angular 8 to get the required tokens google. I was able to pass the token back to the backend resource server to validate the token with google and authorize. Below is the code snippets.

Property File:

```
google:
  client-id: xyz
  iss: accounts.google.com

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Security Config Snippet

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
private String issuer;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
private String jwkSetUri;

@Value("${google.client-id}")
private String clientId;

@Value("${google.iss}")
private String iss;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
        .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder());
}

@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
            JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);        

    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(clientId);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(iss);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<> 
    (withIssuer, audienceValidator);

    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

    return jwtDecoder;
}

}
```

The above snippet works for one authorization server (google in this case) but

**below are my issues**

1. How do Intercept the code to validate if the user exists in our DB first?
2. How do I add support for another authorization server like facebook?